# Android library project with native code packages library twice in the APK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have two Android projects, one is a shared library and one is my application's project. Both projects contain some Java and some native code. When I try and run my APK I receive the following error:

**Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi/libOEShared.so**

My shared library is marked as a library project (Properties->Android->'Is Library') so that I am able to use it's Java code. This presumably copies libOEShared.so for me once.

In order to link my Applications native code with libOEShared I use the NDK Prebuilds feature. Here is my Android.mk:

```
#include shared library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := OEShared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../Shared/OEShared/libs/armeabi/libOEShared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#build App library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := OEApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := OEApp.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2 -lz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := OEShared
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

However, the NDK also copies libOEShared into my Application project's lib folder, resulting in two copies being present in the final APK.

**How can I link my Application's native code to libOEShared without it being automatically duplicated?**

Thank you for you time, this has caused me a lot of frustration so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only linking is required here, instead of build. Linking can be done by using `LOCAL_LD_LIBS` flag. You can try this.

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS  := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Shared/OEShared/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/  \
         -lOEShared
```